# get selected text in an other application

Tags: python, selection, clipboard

I want to have a python script, which will "idle" until some text is selected in an other desktop app, and then store it in a var. Eg:

- User goes into Safari
- User selects a block of text
- In the background, the python script will store that block of text in a var
- Now that the python script has it's var, it can stop "idling" / "pausing" and continue

Think a clipboard, where you don't need to hit "Cmd+C"; all you do is select the text

Cheers!
This is for Mac OSX by the way

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using AppleScript rather than python and have the AppleScript pass the information along to the python if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you want would be hard to do properly, assuming it's possible at all.

For example, without requiring the user to press a key (eg: Cmd+C, Ctrl+C, etc)  how do you expect your application to know when they are done selecting? If I do a click, then shift-click to select a range, am I done? What if I shift-click again? How about if I do a double-click? Triple-click? How does your app know when I'm done making the selection?

Better to make the user explicitly copy the selection to the clipboard. You can fairly easily write an app that uses tkinter or wxpython to poll the clipboard and wait for it to change.