# Python get selected text

Tags: python, macos, selection, clipboard

How would I, using Python "catch" text that a user has selecting in, for example, a web browser? The script would idle in the background, and when a certain key combination is pressed, it "gets" the text the user has selected. Think copy & paste, only it copies to my application instead of a clipboard.

Thanks! I'd like to point out that this will be for Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - get selected text in an other application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021174/python-get-selected-text-in-an-other-application)

Comment: possible duplicate of [OS X Get highlighted text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151417/os-x-get-highlighted-text)

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083313/python-get-mac-clipboard-contents

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `xsel`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xclip xsel -y
   ```
2. Save this as `get-selected.py`

   ```
   import os
   print(os.popen('xsel').read())
   ```
3. Select text
4. Run

   ```
   python get-selected.py
   ```

Comment: for macOS it looks like `xsel` will only work if you have the X11 server running and synchronized to the OS X pasteboard. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860634/8315879. An alternative is `pbcopy`