# Python get mac clipboard contents

Tags: python, macos, clipboard

How can I, using Python (2.7) get the contents of the Mac clipboard. Is there a better way than making a wrapper around pbpaste?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PyObjC is the way to go:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSStringPboardType

pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSStringPboardType)
print u"Pastboard string: %s".encode("utf-8") % repr(pbstring)
```

This only supports text and will return `None` otherwise. You can extend it to support other data types as well, see [NSPastboard Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: On Py3, OS 11.1: `print("Pastboard string: %s" % pbstring)`

Answer (score 16):

Have you looked at the [xerox](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xerox) module?
It is supposed to support windows, OS X and Linux

---

Usage is as follows:

> xerox.copy(u'some string')

And to paste:

> >>> xerox.paste()
>   u'some string'

Comment: Maybe a little too light: On OS X, the `xerox` module is just a wrapper around `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.

Answer (score 9):

If you have installed pandas, you can use the function in pandas as follows:

```
from pandas.io.clipboard import clipboard_get
text = clipboard_get()
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the `xerox` module and most code samples I've found for "get the contents of the Mac clipboard" is that they return plain text only. They don't support hyperlinks, styles, and such, so they're not really able to access the full contents provided by apps like Microsoft Word and Google Chrome.

Standing on the shoulders of others, I finally figured out how to do this. The resulting `richxerox` module is available on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/richxerox) and [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jeunice/richxerox).

Though this question is old, I'm leaving breadcrumbs here because I consistently re-found this page via Google while searching for the answer.

Comment: `richxerox` looks great! I've been looking for something like this. Annoying glitch: though it installs on Python 3, it's Python 2 code. Why? It's easily upgraded.

Comment: I mean that the version that `pip` installed (0.129) has `print` statements without parentheses, it has `iteritems()`, etc. It's not compatible with python 3, and errors out on `import richxerox`. Is there a version I can ask `pip` for what will work? Which one? (I'm asking this because I saw a months-old bug report about recent versions being broken).

Comment: Ha, I guess it's a semantics problem: `129 > 6` :-) I'll fetch the correct version, thanks. (Unfortunately `pip` failed to build PyObjC on my El Capitan box, so I won't be able to actually test it with python 3.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115150/discussion-between-alexis-and-jonathan-eunice).

Comment: Also consider using [jaraco.clipboard](https://pypi.io/project/jaraco.clipboard), which on Mac uses richxerox (and excludes the old versions like 0.129) and provides the same interface on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/)? I guess you could use it to write a Py wrapper which interfaces with [NSPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This might be more "elegant" than shelling out to pbpaste.

Comment: If I knew PyObjC, I wouldn't be writing Mac applications in Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the clipboard (and the screen) with PIL/Pillow on a Mac like this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

# Grab clipboard and save to disk
clip = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
clip.save("clip.png")
```

Just for completeness, you can grab the screen like this:

```
screen = ImageGrab.grab()

# That results in this:
# <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=5120x2880 at 0x110BB7748>

# Save to disk
screen.save("screen.png")
```