# Select All and extract using Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a website. The visible text on the screen is being generated from a database and nowhere to be found in inspect element or the page source code.

I tried manually hitting control A and control C, and it worked perfectly.
Is there a way to hit control A using Selenium and then saving the selected text in a variable?

Comment: Why do you have to select the text with control + A? Getting the element text is not enough?

Comment: The text elements are empty. trust me I've tried. Can you help me with the above method please?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do :) Are you working on Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can first Select all the text in the web element with Selenium as I mentioned previously

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

src_elem = find_element_by_name("source_element")
src_elem.click()
src_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') # select all the text
src_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') # copy it
```

now you can read that text from the clipboard.

```
from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSStringPboardType

pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSStringPboardType)
```

`pbstring` variable contains the clipboard text as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083313/python-get-mac-clipboard-contents)

Comment: When I try to locate any element on this webpage, selenium returns a None.
What should I do in this case?

Comment: can you share a link to that page and elements you trying to locate?

Comment: ```<div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder x-form" method="POST" id="ext-gen13" style="background-color: transparent; padding: 20px; overflow: auto; position: relative;">```

Comment: No, I asked for a link to the web page, not HTML of a single element. Also, probably the problem in your code. So it would be good if you will share your code. Not here in comment, in the question itself so it will be readable