# Mac terminal glitch caused by responding to several input() prompts at once

Tags: python, input, terminal

I am trying to build a python program that takes a copy and pasted version of a table created in Google Sheets and builds that same table in an SQLite database. However, I quickly ran into an issue with how to "feed" the copy and pasted table into the program: copying a table from Google Sheets results in a string where values are separated by tabs (`\t`) and rows are separated by newlines (`\n`). This is an issue because the `input()` function will only record input strings *up until* a newline (which is what the return key types when it is clicked). To fix this issue, I implemented a loop that continually takes input up until the word "done" is input (the following loop also deals with adding NULL in places where there were blanks in the original table, an unrelated issue):

```
complete_stuff = ''
switch = True
while True:
    if switch:
        stuff = input('Dump here: \n')
        switch = False
    else: 
        stuff = input('Compiling... \n')
    if stuff == 'done':
        break
    if stuff[0] == '\t':
        stuff = 'NULL' + stuff
    i = 1
    while i < len(stuff):
        if stuff[i-1]=='\t' and stuff[i]=='\t':
            stuff = stuff[:i] + 'NULL' + stuff[i:]
            i += 1
        i += 1
    if stuff[len(stuff)-1] == '\t':
        stuff = stuff + 'NULL'
    complete_stuff += stuff
    complete_stuff += '\n'
```

Anyways, after an embarrassingly long debugging process, I got my complete code (the loop above plus more) to take in a small copy and pasted table and turn it into an SQL table. The loop I used above to fix the multiple lines of input problem was a little awkward because after pasting, I had to click return twice then enter "done" and hit return again, but since I only made the program for personal use, I concluded that it was fine.
Here's what the program looks like while running in the mac terminal after I have copy and pasted the small table:
[image: terminal pic]

However, when I later tried to paste in a much bigger table, things got a little wacky and the terminal glitched out:

[image: terminal pic2]

As you can see if you look back through the image above, it looks as if my python loop's request for input (what is happening every time you see "Compiling...") and whatever program takes care of pasting appear to be clashing with each other. Eventually, the program just stopped and my computer started emitting this weird sound (it sounded like someone clicking their tongue) about twice a second. The program was still running, I know, because it told me so when I shut it down. 
 So anyways, is there an obvious solution to this issue? Maybe a function like `input()` but that can take multiple lines of input? A way to get my input loop to stop clashing with the pasting mechanism - maybe a way for the pasting mechanism to only paste one line at a time, giving the input loop a chance to submit its input prompt between each pasted line? 
 Thanks

Comment: [Python get mac clipboard contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7083313)

Comment: This didn't exactly answer my question, but it sent me in the right direction, so thanks!