# xsel -o equivalent for OS X

Tags: linux, macos, shell, terminal

Is there an equivalent solution to grab selected text in OS X as 'xsel -o' works for Linux?

Just need the current selection so I can use the text in shell script.

Cheers,
Erik

Answer (score 10):

You can probably install `xsel` on MacOS. (UPDATE: According to Arkku's comment, that will only work if you have the X11 server running and synchronized to the OS X pasteboard.)

If not, a quick Google search turns up `pbcopy` / `pbpaste`, which apparently is pre-installed.

Link: https://github.com/raymontag/keepassc/issues/59

Comment: While you can install `xsel` on OS X, it would only work for people who have the X11 server running and synchronised to the OS X pasteboard… So `pbpaste` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux tool `xsel` is not required as `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` are Apple command line utilities that provide this functionality and are installed by default on macOS.

From the manual page (`man pbcopy`):

> pbcopy, pbpaste - provide copying and pasting to the pasteboard (the
> Clipboard) from command line
>
> pbcopy  takes  the standard input and places it in the specified pasteboard. If no pasteboard is specified, the general
> pasteboard will be
> used by default.  The input is placed in the pasteboard as plain text data unless it begins with the Encapsulated  PostScript
> (EPS)  file
> header or the Rich Text Format (RTF) file header, in which case it is placed in the pasteboard as one of those data types.
>
> pbpaste  removes  the  data  from the pasteboard and writes it to the standard output.  It normally looks first for plain text data
> in the
> pasteboard and writes that to the standard output; if no plain text data is in the pasteboard it looks for Encapsulated PostScript;
> if  no
> EPS is present it looks for Rich Text.  If none of those types is present in the pasteboard, pbpaste produces no output.

To copy *filename.txt* to the clipboard, use the following:

`pbcopy < filename.txt`